# Quarkus problem -> getting warning from quarkus-maven-plugin

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus

Recently I got this warning message, when I have builded `quarkus maven` project. I have tested with several later versions and I think this has to be something local in my environment.

```
[WARNING] Error reading service account token from: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token]. Ignoring
```

And this result in a build failure ...

```
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.kubernetes.deployment.KubernetesDeployer#deploy threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:
```

Although Kubernetes deployment was requested, it however cannot take place, because there was an error during communication with the API Server at `https://kubernetes.default.svc/`

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Like [Tapani Rundgren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11023331/tapani-rundgren) mentioned in the comments, the solution is to export the variables:

```
export KUBERNETES_MASTER=<your server here>
export KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE=<your namspace here>
```

Answer (score 0):

For deployment to Kubernetes to work, you need to be able to communicate with the target cluster.

If you can communicate with the cluster using `kubectl`, then Quarkus will be able to deploy to that cluster as well.

You can also override your local k8s settings for Quarkus specifically, see https://quarkus.io/guides/kubernetes-client#configuration-reference

Comment: I can access the cluster (OpenShift 4.7) with kubectl without issues (using the oc login --token ... thing). It does not seem to get user credentials fron .kube/config. And yes this has been working ok for some time, maybe we have made some changes in our cluster config

Comment: Might be a stupid comment but shouldn't the server be something else than `https://kubernetes.default.svc/` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I am pretty sure something is wrong in the kube config

Comment: True, previously it was not needed (export KUBERNETES_MASTER=<youir server  here>). I assumed that the same info was captured from .kube/config

Comment: And KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE=<your namspace> has to be exported to get it working.

Comment: Now I know why I had this problem - change in our Windows 10 config where HOMEDRIVE=X: does not exist anymore. By exporting HOMEDRIVE=C:\Users\<my userid> Quarkus is able to find the .kube/config file and it works without mentioned env variables (KUBERNETES_*), kubectl does find that config file from users home directory anyway.

Comment: And if you export KUBECONFIG pointing to the the .kube/config file works too